# Does anyone have the rules for Tank Turn Tactics?

Tags: untagged

Does anyone else have a more complete copy (*or an 'as played' copy*) of the rules?

There's a video I discovered:

- The Game Prototype That Had to Be Banned by Its Own Studio
- [YouTube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOYbR-Q_4Hs)
- video by  :  PMG (People Make Games) with Chris Bratt
- featuring :  Halfbrick Studios with Luke Muskat, & Joe Gatling

... which contains a posted copy of the rules in the studio (*@ ~ 8:57*) and thanks to Imanton1@reddit for [transcribing](https://www.reddit.com/r/boardgames/comments/ot1ua2/tank_turn_tactics/h70haag?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) the posted rules:

> TANK TURN TACTICS
>
> Survive to the end and win the cash!
>
> 1st $30 | 2nd $20 | 3rd $15 | 4th $10 | First Blood: $5
>
> RULES
>
> All players start at a random location on the grid, and have 3 hearts and 0 Action Points.
>
> Every 24 hours on a work day, everyone will receive 1 Action Point (AP). The time the point is given may vary day to day.
>
> At any time you like, you can do one of the four following actions:
>
> 1. Move to an adjacent, unoccupied square (1 AP)
> 2. Shoot someone who is within your range (1 AP). Shooting someone removes 1 heart from their health.
> 3. Add a heart (3 AP)
> 4. Upgrade your range (3 AP) At the start of the game, everyone has a range of 2. That is, they can shoot or trade with somehow within 2 squares of them. Upgrading your shooting range increases this by 1 square each time.
>
> If a player is reduced to zero (0) hearts, then they are dead. Any action points the dead player had are transferred to the player who killed them. Dead players remain on the board and not removed.
>
> Players are able to send gifts of hearts or actions points to any player currently within their range.
>
> Dead players can have a heart sent to them. This will revive that player who will have 1 heart and 0 AP.
>
> ADDITIONAL NOTES
>
> Dead players form a jury. Each day they vote, and whoever received most votes will be 'haunted', and not revive any AP for that day.
>
> Once a day, at a random time, a hear will spawn on the field. The first player to move into the square containing the heart will revive an additional heart.
>
> The game ends when a clear 1st, 2nd, and 3rd place can be determined. Once there are 4 players left, they will see if they can agree on the placing.
>
> Action points are secret! Probably a good idea to try and hide how many you have.
>
> You can't win this game without making some friends and stabbing some backs. Probably.

***However***, there's a discrepancy between the video and the rules...  If you listen to the video (*@ ~ 8:30*), you'll note that the jury does not operate as per the printed rules.?. Instead he states that:

> <{ once per day, the jury gets to pick who they help out; any player(s) who receive three (3) votes from the jury gets an extra action point }>

In addition, there are timing items that are not discussed ..

- for instance what if two players want to both move into the same square at the same time?
- secondly, given : TankA & TankB only have one heart each .. if TankA shoots TankB, can TankB return fire? .. or is it a *race* to who "registers" an order first?
- finally, given : TankA & TankB only have two hearts each, & two AP's each, can TankA "register" two shoot orders first, before TankB can even return a single shot?

Finally, what about hearts?...  with a literal interpretation of the rules, there's nothing stopping you from having more than three (3) hearts.?.  But was that how it was really played?

Comment: Hope someone finds the right game rules. Good luck!